# In JavaScript, if I installed a library, would I still be able to use normal JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, libraries

If I installed a library, like chart.js or processing.js, would I still be able to use standard JavaScript without uninstalling the libraries?

Comment: Yes, you would.

Comment: Yes, without problem. Libraries are just there to extend the capabilities of a language, not replace it. Use as many as you like.

Comment: libraries..think of it like some additional code or a complex function you have written in JavaScript out of your main program and you call it inside your program, then yes you are writing the same JavaScript everywhere.

Comment: A better question would be, how would a library prevent you from using "standard javascript"? I mean sure, you talk about "installing/uninstalling a library", and don't specify what "standard javascript" is (a library could very well overwrite native prototypes or whatever), but i feel you are imagining something like normal keywords suddenly not working anymore.